# Vanishing point of perspective projection representation

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, transformation, projective-geometry, projective-space

I synchronized with @David k's [first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285168/difference-between-parallel-projection-and-perspective-projection) and [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288470/special-cases-of-perspective-projection) answer regarding perspective and parallel projection. From the first question I understand that the image on the screen is typically described in horizontal and vertical coordinates, that is 2D points. But from the second question, I understand that images on the screen are realistic if they use perspective projection which has 3D coordinates.

My confusion is that how we show the image on the screen with 2D points by perspective projection?

The point $(x,y,z)$ is projected to position $(x_p,y_p,z_{vp})$ on the view plane. Since the view plane is placed at position $z_{vp}$ along the $z_v$ axis. So when $z_{vp}=0$ projectors (projection vectors) do not converge towards a projection reference point in parallel projection. But in perspective projection, when $z_{vp}=0$, it is reduced to parallel projection, but the projectors converge at the centre of projection. Am I correct above these concepts?

The vanishing point in perspective projection which is 3D coordinates could be represented in the projective plane as $(x, y, z, 0).$ Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My confusion is that how we show the image on the screen with 2D points by perspective projection?

We start with a point in the 3D model of the scene;
this has 3D coordinates $(x,y,z)$
As you know, coordinates $(x,y,z)$ are projected to coordinates $(x_p,y_p,z_{vp})$, which are coordinates in the view plane.

So already, because the view plane is a *plane*, everything has been reduced to two dimensions. But to transfer it to the computer screen, we recognize that the $z_{vp}$ is the same at all points in the view plane.
Comparing two projected points, only $x_p$ and/or $y_p$ can be different.

From $x_p$ we get the horizontal coordinate on the computer screen.
From $y_p$ we get the vertical coordinate on the computer screen.
These two coordinates are enough to select the correct pixel on the 2D computer screen where the projected point should be displayed.

> But in perspective projection when $z_{vp}=0$, it is reduced to parallel projection, but projectors are converged to centre of projection.

Yes, the projectors converge to the center of the projection (which must be at a non-zero $z$ coordinate).

No, the perspective projection is **not** reduced to parallel projection just by moving the view plane to $z_{vp}=0$. Perspective projection remains perspective projection no matter where you put the view plane.
(Just keep the center the projection off the view plane, because if you put the center on the view plane you don't get a perspective *or* a parallel projection;
everything just collapses onto the center point and you get no picture.)

> The vanishing point in perspective projection which is 3D coordinates could be represents in projective plane as $(x, y, z, 0).$

Nobody uses four coordinates for a projective plane. The so-called *points at infinity* are written $(x, y, 0).$

The *projective plane* is a mathematical extension of the ordinary Euclidean plane.
It's connected to the theory of perspective projection but you don't need to use the projective plane as a tool to perform any of the standard projections of computer models to images
(and I do not see any way in which you would *want* to use it).

It is certainly possible mathematically to construct a perspective projection **of** a projective plane. Points at infinity would be projected at vanishing points in the projection. But this has nothing to do with the standard methods you will find when you look in textbooks and lectures on how perspective projection is done in software.
Looking at the references posted in your earlier questions, for example, no projective plane is used in any way anywhere in them.

---

(Community wiki because I feel it would be unethical to take credit for answering a question that was directly caused by my own answers to previous questions.)

Comment: ----"So already, because the view plane is a plane, everything has been reduced to two dimensions"--- could you explain little bit, what you want to say?

Comment: help me to understand my final confusion.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289886/difference-between-2d-pipeline-and-3d-pipeline

Comment: please help. Without your answer my concepts Will be incomplete. Help me. Please.

Comment: still I am waiting for your answer